# Javascript closure setTimeout interval issue

Tags: javascript

Why is the following logged every 1 second?  I'm multiplying 1000 milliseconds to the increment. Shouldn't my logs show up after 1 second, then 2 seconds, then 3 seconds?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(r) {
    setTimeout(
      function() { 
        console.log(r)
      } 
    , r * 1000 );
  })(i)
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dmj3dd2L/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually nothing wrong with your loop brother. What happens is that the setTimeout executions executed simultaneously. Remember your small loop execution time is just a matter of milliseconds.

**Proof of concept.**

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            console.log(new Date() + " Loop Executed: " + (i + 1));
            (function (r) {
                setTimeout(
                  function () {
                      console.log(new Date() + " " + r)
                  }
                , (r * 1000));
            })(i)
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

it's working correctly, basically, the loop serves as shorthand for writing this:

```
setTimeout( function(){ console.log(0) }, 1000)
setTimeout( function(){ console.log(1) }, 2000)
setTimeout( function(){ console.log(2) }, 3000)
setTimeout( function(){ console.log(3) }, 4000)
setTimeout( function(){ console.log(4) }, 5000)
```

so it would make sense that each goes off one after the other kinda looking like this:

```
▀
▀▀
▀▀▀
▀▀▀▀
▀▀▀▀▀
```

what you might be looking for is

```
(function newTimeout( seconds ){
  if( seconds > 4 ) return;
  console.log(seconds);
  setTimeout( function(){
    newTimeout( seconds + 1 )
  }, seconds * 1000);
})(0);
```

which would kinda look like this

```
▀
 ▀▀
   ▀▀▀
      ▀▀▀▀
          ▀▀▀▀▀
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the following logged every 1 second?

because the first one is logged after 0 x 1000ms, the second one after 1 x 1000ms, third one after 2 x 1000ms ... so, after 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 seconds

> Shouldn't my logs show up after 1 second, then 2 seconds, then 3 seconds?

actually after 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 seconds - but it's not cumulative, you're starting ALL the timeouts at virtually the same time

Answer (score 2):

That's because calling `setTimeout` will not stop the executing of code. The loop will continue and do all the `setTimeout()` in each loop from the start. That's why it logs every second. They do go off after 1, 2, 3, and 4 seconds, but start all at the same time.